# How to upload folder with sub folder to Amazon S3

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need upload a folder with sub folders on Amazon S3.

I create this code `saverepertoire2` But this code upload only files in the folder.

```
public String uploadFolder1(Path filePath) {

        PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(filePath.getFileName().toString())
                .build();
    
        // Put the object into the bucket
        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = s3AsyncClient.putObject(objectRequest,
                AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(filePath));
        future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
            try {
                if (resp != null) {
                    System.out.println("Object uploaded. Details: " + resp);
                } else {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
    
                // s3Client.close();
            }
        });
    
        future.join();
    
        return "Your file " + filePath + " was successfully uploaded ASync";
    }
    
    public void saverepertoire2(String path) throws IOException {
        Path path1 = Paths.get(path);
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path1)) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(x -> uploadFolder1(x));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that it only uploads one folder, or are you saying that all files (even from other folders) end up in the _same_ folder? What does `filePath.getFileName().toString()` do? Does it strip off the path so that it only has the 'filename' without the location?

Comment: Please add an Answer to help future readers, or feel free to Delete the question if it is not likely to help people in future.